# use bash function in sed command

Tags: linux, bash, sed, command

I have a file called `d1.txt`

```
line1
line2
```

and `a.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p  'Name : ' domain
#Not Working Command: sed -i s/$/' >> domain-js-m1-1.js/ d1.txt
```

I want to add `' >> $domain-1.js` in the last of every line in `d1.txt` using script `a.sh`
I try this cmd but this is not adding text from input

```
sed -i s/$/' >> $domain-1.js/ d1.txt
```

`read -p 'Name: ' domain`  If I give `shin` in input
then I want this in output

```
line1' >> shin-1.js
line2' >> shin-1.js
```

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use backslash and double qoutes, like so:

```
sed -i 's/$/'\'" >> $domain-1.js/" d1.txt
```